# How to find simplified status?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{x^4 + x^2y - x^2y^2-y^3}{x^3 + xy - x^2y-y^2}$$ How do i find this simpiflied status? I've an idea: $x-y$. I need your help. Thanks for everyone.

Comment: By simplifying, even if takes a few steps to do so.  So that raises the question: What have you tried yourself, before asking here (and please add your work on the problem within your post.) And what do you mean about the "idea":  $x-y$, and how does that idea address your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you don't "see" the factorizations offhand. You can find them the long way by noting that:

- the numerator $x^4 + x^2y - x^2y^2-y^3 = x^4 - (y^2-y) \cdot x^2 -y^3$ is a quadratic in $x^2$ with roots $\frac{1}{2}\big(y^2-y) \pm \sqrt{(y^2-y)^2+4y^3}\big)\,$ $=\frac{1}{2}\big(y^2-y \pm \sqrt{y^4+2y^3+y^2}\big)\,$ $=\frac{1}{2}\big(y^2-y \pm (y^2+y)\big)\,$ $=\{y^2, -y\}\,$, so the numerator factors as $(x^2-y^2)(x^2+y)$
- the denominator $x^3 + xy - x^2y-y^2 = -y^2 -(x^2-x)y+x^3\,$ is a quadratic in $y$ with roots $\frac{-1}{2}\big(x^2-x\pm\sqrt{(x^2-x)^2+4x^3}\big)\,$ $=\cdots\,$ $=\{-x^2, x\}\,$, so the denominator factors as $-(y-x)(y+x^2)\,$.

The fraction then becomes $\require{cancel}\cfrac{(x^2-y^2)\cancel{(x^2+y)}}{(x-y)\cancel{(y+x^2)}}=x+y\,$.

Comment: I disapprove that someone would have down-voted this. Students appreciate generously thorough answers like this very much.

Comment: @user56478 Some students, do, indeed, (I wouldn't call it appreciating, but rather conning) especially when the student fails to do any work on their part, and asks, essentially, "do my homework for me."  And unfortunately, some users oblige by fulfilling that demand.

Comment: @amWhy Mine was *not* the first posted answer, and once there is an answer already I consider it fair game to point out alternatives to the OP. To each his own, I guess.

Comment: @user56478 And I disapprove of someones who enable students to get by without effort.

Comment: @dxiv  Ahhh, by your reasoning, so, if someone runs through a red stoplight, since that someone did, everyone else is entitled to do so too?

Comment: @amWhy That's a forced analogy at best, and here is not the place to argue this, anyway. You can take it to meta if you feel so strongly about it.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{array}{cl}
&\dfrac{x^4 + x^2y - x^2y^2-y^3}{x^3 + xy - x^2y-y^2} \\
=&\dfrac{x^2(x^2+y) - y^2(x^2+y)}{x(x^2+y) - y(x^2+y)} \\
=&\dfrac{(x^2-y^2)(x^2+y)}{(x-y)(x^2+y)} \\
=&\dfrac{(x+y)(x-y)(x^2+y)}{(x-y)(x^2+y)} \\
=&x+y
\end{array}$$